# Changing global css with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, global

I have a background image that is in a style tag at the top of my html. And I want to change it when it turns to night time where the user is. So during the day it is imageA and during night time it is imageB.
The reason the css is in the header is because of my file layout and it wouldn't be able to access the image otherwise.

How do I change this global css styling from an external js file? I want to change the background image value. Any help would be great thank you.

```js
    let d;

    d = new Date();

    var now = d.toString().slice(16,18);

    console.log(now);
    if (now <= 5, now >= 20) {
        console.log("it is night time")
        //the code to change the image would be here
    } else {
        console.log("it is daytime")
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Seldom Seen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flip.css" />
        <!--the lines below here is the part i want to change-->
        <style>
            .bg-image{
            background-image:url("images/imageA.png");
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

Comment: I made them 1 snippet instead of 2 because one snippet can't change another, it just makes sense.

Comment: Why go the hard way? Just set two classes, one for day and one for night and toggle between them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but you can use this snippet to change the background-image through JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".bg-image").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/imageB)";
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be document.querySelector(".bg-image")[0]
?

Comment: querySelector, unlike getElementsByClassName or getElementsByTagName, returns only the first match.

Comment: @Klaassiek, no. `querySelector` returns `Element | null`. You're thinking of `querySelectorAll` which returns `NodeList`.

Comment: Ah. Yeah. Confused it for queySelectorAll. Sorry

Comment: Thank you very much this has worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any ways to modify CSS in the header using JavaScript, but here are two approaches that would solve your problem:

1. Assign one of the background images to an additional class, which overrides the original assignment by CSS specificity.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Seldom Seen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flip.css" />
    <!--the lines below here is the part i want to change-->
    <style>
        .bg-image{
           background-image:url("images/imageDay.png");
        }
        .bg-image.night{
          background-image:url("images/imageNight.png");
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

```
const bg = document.querySelector('.bg-image');

let d;

d = new Date();

var now = d.toString().slice(16,18);

console.log(now);
if (now <= 5, now >= 20) {
    console.log("it is night time");
    bg.classList.add('night');
} else {
    console.log("it is daytime");
    bg.classList.remove('night');
}
```

2. Modify the style attribute of the element inline:

```js
if (now <= 5, now >= 20) {
    document.querySelector('.bg-image').style.backgroundImage = url('./images/imageNight.jpg');
} 
else {
    document.querySelector('.bg-image').style.backgroundImage = url('./images/imageDay.jpg');
}
```